# Prevent fraction formatting in equation in Office 2019?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equation-editor

The office equation editor by default converts "1/3" and similar sequences to fractions. In some places however (e.g. in exponents) this may be undesirable. Is there some convenient way to suppress the default behavior?

### Example

Let's say that I have an expression `e^(-iEt/\hbar)` that I want to typeset as an equation. Typing it in this manner will result in

[image]

Fractions in exponents, especially when created for only a single symbol, don't really help readability. I prefer to typeset it as

[image]

but in order to achieve this I have to type `e^(-iEt\hbar)` and go back to add the `/` after the fact, which is inconvenient for large expressions, so I am searching for a more convenient way of creating partially linearized expressions.

I recall being able to undo automatic conversions such as from "a/b" to a fraction with <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> in Office 2010, but in Office 2019 this doesn't seem to work. E.g. typing <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> will result in a fraction, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> afterwards will delete the fraction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Short answer

Write `a\/b` instead of `a/b`.

An alternative for larger expressions can be `\ldiv`, which changes in size and adds more spacing. E.g., the sequence `((1+3)/4)\ldiv{(1-3)/4)` will produce

[image]

#### Long answer

The trick to understanding the current equation editor seems to be the [[UnicodeMath standard]](https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v3.pdf). For the specific question, the relevant part would be:

```
The fraction operator is given by the usual solidus / (U+002F).
So the simple built-up fraction

    
    –––
     

appears in linear format as abc/d. To force a display of a 
normal-size linear fraction, one can use \/ (backslash followed by slash).
```